# Add int data to Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, integer

I'm starting to use firebase and flutter and I'm trying to add data to Firestore. I succeed when adding a String, but I'm having problems when trying to add a integer (such as age). I know that I could use age as a String and set the keyboard to number only, but I'm intrigued why it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 String name = '';
 int  age = 0;
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'name'),
            onChanged: (value) {
              name = value;
              ;
            },
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'age'),
            onChanged: (value) {
              age = value as int;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('add info into firestore'),
            onPressed: () {
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionPath').add({
                'name': '$name',
                'age': age,
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
 }
```

In debug, I'm getting:

> Exception caught by widgets ═══════════════════════════════════════════
> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

Comment: What exact line is giving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're trying to cast a `String` to an `int`. You should instead [parse](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/int/parse.html) the `String` to an `int`.

Here's a quote from [The Dart type system | Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system) that gives an insight as to why the typecast failed at runtime:

> Dart’s type system, like the type systems in Java and C#, is sound. It
> enforces that soundness using a combination of static checking
> (compile-time errors) and runtime checks. For example, assigning a
> String to int is a compile-time error. Casting an object to a String
> using as String fails with a runtime error if the object isn’t a
> String.

**Solution**:

Change this line in the age `TextField's` `onChanged` method:

```
age = value as int;
```

to this:

```
age = int.parse(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your collection, you have to make something called a Document. The document is allowed to contain things like Strings, ints, bools, Lists, Maps, etc. The reason why you are only able to store Strings at the moment is that your code implicitly tries to create a new Document with the name of $name variable and as a sidenote, a Document name can only be a String, which is why it ignores your age int.

In order to fix your issue, this is what your onPressed() function should look like:

```
onPressed: () {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionPath').doc('documentName').set({
      'name' : '$name',
      'age' : age
    });
  }
```

Inside your Collection called 'collectionPath', this code will create a Document called 'documentName' (you can change this to whatever you want) and inside this Document, it will set the name and age variables. The set() method is called on the Document and its parameter is a Map that consists of the variables you want to store.

If you have any questions, let me know.